# Matplotlib Animation, plotting data from a while True:

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, while-loop, raspberry-pi3

I'm running a script on a Raspberry Pi, where I pull some data from an accelerometer, and I want to continuously update a plot. I've read around and watched some youtube videos and I've decided for the Matplotlib animation.

Now everything kinda works but the plot doesn't really get drawn before I KeyboardInterrupt the script. And I see why, because the plot function is inside the loop. I've tried moving it out of the loop,but then it doesn't work at all.

```
       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
       import matplotlib.animation as animation
       from matplotlib import style
       style.use("fivethirtyeight")

       import time
       import board
       import busio
       import adafruit_tca9548a
       import adafruit_adxl34x

       i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)


       tca = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c)


       ad1 = adafruit_adxl34x.ADXL345(tca[0])
       ad2 = adafruit_adxl34x.ADXL345(tca[2])


       fig = plt.figure()
       ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


       def animate(i):
           G = []
           while True:

              x,y,z = ad2.acceleration


              acc = [x,y,z]
              acc_abs = [abs(a) for a in acc]
              i = acc_abs.index(max(acc_abs))
              stor = acc[i]

              if stor>0:
                  stor = stor-10.52
              elif stor<0:
                  stor =  stor+10.52

              time.sleep(1)

              G.append(stor)
              ax1.clear()
              ax1.plot(G)

      ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval =1000)
      plt.show()
```

Comment: You're not meant to use a while loop inside the animating function, because that function is already what is called repeatedly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thank you. Do recommend a certain way I should do it? I've tried taking the while loop out of the function, and put it in before it

Comment: There should not be any `while` loop in your complete script.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see the logic of not having it in the script, but I don't know how I can continuously pick up data from the sensors if I don't have it.

Comment: The animate function *is* your loop.

Comment: yes of course! Thank you! :-)